# How to configure EF one-to-one relationship with both optional FK

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes that both have optional foreign keys of one another.
I'm getting the error "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types Device and ServiceUnit"
Here are the classes:

```
class Device{
   int Id {get;set;}
   int? ServiceUnitId {get;set;}
   ServiceUnit ServiceUnit {get;set;}
}

class ServiceUnit{
   int Id {get;set;}
   int? DeviceId{get;set;}
   Device Device{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your mappings?

Comment: @Kamo, no mappings yet